# iOS Parse 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Im trying to add parse data into my table array and i get'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

```
PFQuery *query31 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Salesman"];
        [query31 whereKey:@"SalesNo" equalTo:self.tbl22];
      //   query31.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
        [query31 getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (!object) {
                NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
            } else {
                self.salesman = [object objectForKey:@"Salesman"];
                NSLog(@"salesStr is %@",self.salesman);
            }
        }];

 tableData2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:t21, t22, t23, t24, t25, nil];
```

here is were i get the crash t22 = self salesman

```
if ([_formController isEqual: @"Leads"]) {

    if ( ( ![t22 isEqual:[NSNull null]] ) && ( [self.tbl22 length] != 0 ) )
            {t22 = self.salesman;
    } else { t22 = @"None"; }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.listTableView]) {
        return [tableData count];
    } else if ([tableView isEqual:self.listTableView2]) {
        return [tableData count];
    } else if ([tableView isEqual:self.newsTableView]) {
        return 1;
    }
      return 0;
}

#pragma mark TableView Delegate Methods
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([tableView isEqual:self.listTableView]) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }
        //need to reload table (void)viewDidAppear to get fonts to change but its annoying
    myCell.textLabel.text = [tableData4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
   [myCell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    myCell.detailTextLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8.0];
   [myCell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    return myCell;
}
    else if ([tableView isEqual:self.listTableView2]) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"NewCell2";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2]; }
        //need to reload table (void)viewDidAppear to get fonts to change but its annoying
    myCell.textLabel.text = [tableData3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
   [myCell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    myCell.detailTextLabel.text = [tableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8.0];
   [myCell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        //draw red vertical line
    UIView *vertLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, myCell.frame.size.height)];
    vertLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [myCell.contentView addSubview:vertLine];

    return myCell;
}
    else if ([tableView isEqual:self.newsTableView]) {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"detailCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *myCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1]; }
     //need to reload table (void)viewDidAppear to get fonts to change but its annoying
    myCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, myCell.frame.size.width, 0.0f, 400.0f);
    myCell.leadtitleLabel.text = self.lnewsTitle;
    myCell.leadtitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    myCell.leadtitleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
   [myCell.leadtitleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    myCell.leadsubtitleLabel.text = @"Yahoo Finance 2 hrs ago";
    myCell.leadsubtitleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
   [myCell.leadsubtitleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    myCell.leadreadmore.text = @"Read more";
    myCell.leadreadmore.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
    myCell.leadnews.text = comments;
    myCell.leadnews.numberOfLines = 0;
    myCell.leadnews.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8.0];
   [myCell.leadnews setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

return myCell;
}
```

when i run log i get one result Salesman name

```
NSLog(@"salesStr is %@",self.salesman);
salesStr is Adam Monteleone
```

Comment: Can you tell more specific what you are doing here? What's the data type of the t22?

Comment: i'm trying to get one string salesman from parse and want to put it into and existing array (t22) put into a tableview

Comment: Your variable names lack clarity. You haven't posted any lines of code that are related to an `NSArray`. Please append the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: I updated my answer already. You probably go debug your code.

Comment: You use the size of `tableData` to control how many rows are filled but you use other arrays (2, 3, 4) to provide data.  How sure are you that all the arrays are the same length?

Comment: very sure it works...it must be with the parse index of self.salesman = [object objectForKey:@"Salesman"] thats giving me the problem and can't figure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you array is empty and you try to access the index 1 which is not able to get it. You better debug yourself.

And if you want to do the introspection on the `NSString`, you only need to use the `length` method to check. It will return `false` if your NSString is either nil or empty.

Comment: Lucas when i do an NSLog there is a string..see above

Comment: i used this approach to get one item in my parse query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock should i go another route

Comment: Sorry, really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is self.salesman returning nil in your NSLog for the query where you set it?

Comment: no...it's returning Adam Monteleone ..which is good..but when i put it into my array t22 = self salesman....i get 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]